# Rename files in directory in batch

Tags: batch-file

Can anyone help with a bat file to rename files in a windows directory from e.g.

```
this-image-file-name (1).tif
this-image-file-name (2).tif
this-image-file-name (3).tif
that-pic-file-name (1).tif
that-pic-file-name (2).tif
```

to

```
this-image-file-name-1.tif
this-image-file-name-2.tif
this-image-file-name-3.tif
that-pic-file-name-1.tif
that-pic-file-name-2.tif
```

basically strip out the space and parentheses and add in the hyphen?

```
    @echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern= ("
Set "Replace=-"

For /R %%a in (*.tif) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Set "Pattern=)"
Set "Replace="

For /R %%a in (*.tif) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

without the /D /r it works fine in the current folder but i need it to work on all subfolders

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Updated with my code

Comment: With `FOR /D` you get directories, not files. `FOR /?` helps

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081): `jren "\s*\((\d+)\)(?=\.tif$)" "-$1" /fm "*(*).tif"`

Comment: ```For /R %%a in (*.tif) Do (``` returns "The syntex of the command is incorrect". I have also tried with a path

Answer (score 1):

I commend to your attention the output of `FOR /?` or `HELP FOR`, or alternatively the documentation for [`FOR` at SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html). The `/D` switch instructs the command to process **D**irectories, ignoring files (that is, it would cause this batch file to attempt to rename directories, which is *not* what you want). If you are always going to start this batch file in the directory where the files to be renamed can be found, then `/R` and `/S` are equivalent; you must use `/R` if you wish to pass a starting folder to the command (see [`FOR /R` at SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)).

Your batch file should work as you desire if you **remove the `/D`** in both `FOR` statements.